# How can we use Amazon cognito as a identity provider for other applications like google or facebook

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, openid, amazon-cognito

We can associate google, Twitter, or any Oauth2.0 authorisation with AWS cognito. But, can we use our cognito as Oauth2.0 or an identity provider for other websites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon Cognito is an OIDC provider. So if website supports OIDC, you can use Cognito as an identity provider. You can find more details about OIDC configurations here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html

Comment: Thanks Vinay Kushwaha for sharing the link can you please share any example where we are using cognito as an identity provider?